# Dojo "TypeError {stack: (...), message: "undefined is not a function"}" while trying to show a gif on ajax load

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I am trying to show a loading gif while making an ajax call , below is my code and I am getting a error at the show statement , and console is throwing.

```
TypeError {stack: (...), message: "undefined is not a function"}
```

below is my code

```
require(["dojo/_base/xhr"], function(xhr) {
    xhr.get({
        url: uri,
        handleAs: "text",
        load: function(data) {
            require(["dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/_base/window"], function(domConstruct, win) {
                domConstruct.place("<div id='loadgif'><img src='/22.gif' ></img></div> ", win.body());
            });

            dojo.byId("loadgif").show();
            console.log(data);
            txt = data;
            console.log(txt);
            console.log(txt.split("/")[0]);
            console.log(txt.split("/")[2]);
            dojo.byId("loadgif").hide();
            },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: will you be able to show the line where that error being thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `DOMNode::show()` is not a function, so the following lines won't work:

```
dojo.byId("loadgif").show();
dojo.byId("loadgif").hide();
```

The best way to do so is by using the `dojo/dom-sytle::set()` function, for example:

```
domStyle.set(dom.byId("loadgif"), "display", "block");
domStyle.set(dom.byId("loadgif"), "display", "none");
```

However, there are a few other strange things as well. You're only showing the loadgif for a split second, after the AJAX request has been completed (since it's in the `load` callback).

You should move that piece of code outside the `load` callback if you want to show your indicator during the network request as well, for example:

```
require([ "dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(xhr, domConstruct, dom, domStyle, win) {
    domConstruct.place("<div id='loadgif'><img src='/22.gif' /></div>", win.body());
    var node = dom.byId("loadgif");
    domStyle.set(node, "display", "block");
    xhr.get({
        url: uri,
        handleAs: "text",
        load: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            txt = data;
            console.log(txt);
            console.log(txt.split("/")[0]);
            console.log(txt.split("/")[2]);
            domStyle.set(node, "display", "none");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you can simply move the `require()` functions together.

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/23VKq/